installing anchors into lath and plaster on brick
I messed up installing a shelf and I don't know what to do. The wall is lath and plaster, so I got Hillman hollow wall anchors. The first anchor I installed worked great, the wall was hollow in that spot, unfortunately I measured wrong, so I moved everything over an inch and started again.
This time I hit brick behind the plaster. I could drill one deep enough and I used the anchor anyway, but it seems sturdy.
I already drilled the other 2 large holes for anchors, but I can't drill deep enough for anchors, so now what? I'm installing Ikea shelf brackets so the screw head has to be the right size to fit through the keyhole in the bracket.

There are brick/masonry anchors.  Hollow wall anchors are iffy for shelves depending on the weight place on them.

Thank you, are there long masonry anchors? Because now that I have already drilled, they would have to reach farther than I drilled for the first anchors.
